# Condition with an and bit to bit - C code

Tags: c

I want to know what this code does

```
if(a & b) {....}
```

Where `a` and `b` are both `int`'s.

What must be the value of ( `a & b` for 8 bits as example ) to execute that condition

Comment: Have you done some research ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&` here is the bitwise `&` ( [bitwise AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) ). It does the AND operation ( [AND gate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AND_gate) ).

This is the truth table for an AND gate

```
+----------+-----------+-------------+
|     X    |     Y     |    X & Y    |
+----------+-----------+-------------+
|     0    |     0     |      0      |
|     0    |     1     |      0      |
|     1    |     0     |      0      |
|     1    |     1     |      1      |
+----------+-----------+-------------+
```

Now, the bitwise `&` takes the binary of each of the two numbers on either side and perform an and on each of it's corresponding bits. For example

```
   0011 0110                   //  54
 & 0001 0001                   //  17
---------------
   0001 0000                   //  16
```

So, an example for your condition ( `if ( a & b )` ) to be satisfied is

```
a = 3;
b = 1;
```

So

```
  0000 0011      //   3 
& 0000 0001      //   1 
------------
  0000 0001      //   1
```

which is 1, that is `true`.

The only conditions where it fails are when all corresponding bits of `a` and `b` are not the same or they are zero.

For example, for

```
a=3;
b=4;
```

So

```
   0000 0011         //   3
 & 0000 0100         //   0
----------------
   0000 0000         //   0
```

Which is 0, and hence `false`,and whenever the resultant is false, the if statement does not execute.

So, for any value for `a & b` other than 0, that if condition is executed.

Answer (score 0):

An example should clarify:

```
a  =0b 1111 0000
b  =0b 0001 0001
a&b=0b 0001 0000
```

Only where the n'th bits is 1 in both a and b will give 1 in a&b n'th bit. If the value a&b is different from 0, the if-statement will be truthy.